# How do I create a PHP page which can accept file uploads?

Tags: php, file-upload

I want to upload a file to my server from some application. How can I code a PHP page to accept this file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The application should just include the file in an HTTP POST request as would an HTML form with an `input` of type `file`.  In the PHP code, the posted file contents would be available in the `$_FILES` array.

Lots more information [here](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php).

Keep in mind that the concept of a "file" doesn't mean the same thing over HTTP that it does on a local computer or on the target server.  In HTTP, the "file" is just a stream of data wrapped in an HTTP request or response with a given content type and various other headers, no different from a web page or an image or any other request/response.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest reading the PHP manual chapter on [handling file uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php)